# Build throws always an error with Nodejs deployment

Tags: node.js, openshift

I recently saw Openshift and It was interesting option to test my projects on the cloud..

So I have tried it and after trying to deploy an angular project and react project they failed, then I was actually thinking the problem is my end.. but I even tried the default angular-cli project and it also failed after 30 mins of waiting for the build, I am not sure how Openshift says you can deploy any Nodejs application, if only their example works.

Here is the repository [GIT](https://github.com/deeq14/digizone) I used

And from the logs this what is says--

Status:  Failed

```
Cloning "https://github.com/deeq14/digizone.git" ...
    Commit: 04a67f219c3f44ec0d456b218ca96a5591310978 (Update .angular-cli.json)
    Author: deeq14 <***@gmail.com>
    Date:   Tue Jun 20 16:28:31 2017 +0300
Pulling image "registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/nodejs-6-rhel7@sha256:b84c9a9027eab85386fc9ef12044c44ab8f622916e7232ecfe1486398d11b490" ...
Pulling image "registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/nodejs-6-rhel7@sha256:b84c9a9027eab85386fc9ef12044c44ab8f622916e7232ecfe1486398d11b490" ...
---> Installing application source ...
---> Building your Node application from source
/usr/libexec/s2i/assemble: line 51:    12 Killed                  npm install
error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/nodejs-6-rhel7@sha256:b84c9a9027eab85386fc9ef12044c44ab8f622916e7232ecfe1486398d11b490
```

I can now clone that GIT, run npm install and it works on my localhost

so whats the problem?

Comment: Is this on OpenShift Online? The status of the cluster can be seen at https://status.starter.openshift.com/ There are currently issues with build failures which are being investigated. It is likely related to that.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton yes openshift online, my cluster is starter-us-west-2 which fine so no matter what I always get build errors, if the nodejs deployment contains a lot of node_modules.. there is no problem when it contains less node_modules

Comment: The killing off a build pod can occur when it uses too much memory. The ``npm`` installer may be prone to memory bloat when installing a lot of packages as have seen people having them killed off before. You may be able to go into the build configuration and override the allowed amount of memory for the build. Run ``oc explain bc.spec.resources`` to see what settings can be changed.

Comment: ok I will let you know and try now